# Setting up recaptcha with devise rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, recaptcha

I followed the devise wiki [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise) and I get a template error when I try to create a new user. This is what I have done.

Set up my public and private keys in config/environment.rb

```
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY']='examplepubkey'
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = 'exampleprivkey'
```

I then added the gem to my gemfile and ran bundle install

```
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
```

I then added a registrations controller by running rails g controller Registrations create and adding this to the file.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
    else
      build_resource
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      flash[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code and click submit."
      render_with_scope :new
    end
  end  

end
```

I also added the recaptcha tags to views/devise/registrations/new

```
<div><%= recaptcha_tags %></div>
```

Then I edited the routes file to look like:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }, :path => "users"
```

When I check out the link in my browser I get

```
Template is missing

Missing template registrations/new with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], 
:formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * 
"/Users/thomascioppettini/rails_projects/want_freight/app/views" *
"/Users/thomascioppettini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@standard/gems/devise-1.4.5/app/views"
```

[edit]

I was able to get the captcha to appear by deleting the bit I added about controllers, but the captcha passes when I add any text into the text field or leave it blank.

[edit2]
I was able to figure out how to solve the problem and will post the solution when stack overflow will allow me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the recaptcha to work by destroying the controller I had set up using rails g controller Registrations create and adding the files by hand as this site suggests. [setting up recaptcha with devise](http://www.deploymentzone.com/2011/05/26/recaptcha-devise-and-rails-3/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+deploymentzone+%28Deployment+Zone%29)